# Why is "he" twice as common as "she" in the English language

Tags: personal-pronouns, grammatical-gender, frequency-analysis

When you look at word frequency data in English such as the [Corpus Of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.wordfrequency.info/intro.asp) **he** appears on 16th place with 6500 occurrences per mil and **she** at 35th place with 3210 per mil.

This is a factor of 2 in usage.

Compared to many languages, in English, *he* and *she* are only used for animate subjects, with *it* serving serving as the inanimate subject. And as far as I'm aware in an ambiguous or neutral context *he or she* or *they* would be used.

Therefore the null hypothesis would predict that *he* and *she* would have the same frequency, being used as pronouns by almost exactly half of the population each.

Is there something I'm missing? Or does this simply point to some deeply rooted sexism and gender imbalance?

If older works were included I could easily imagine this phenomenon being as strong as it is, because all the writers were men, but in the current language Corpus?

At the link above you can download a spreadsheet with a further subdivision of frequencies in different context and this relationship holds in most of them:

| rank | lemma | PoS | freq | perMil | range | disp | blog | web | TVM | spok | fic | mag | news | acad | blogPM | webPM | TVMPM | spokPM | ficPM | magPM | newsPM | acadPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | he | p | 6467470 | 6512.91 | 331648 | 0.97 | 519986 | 638982 | 912036 | 974382 | 1671940 | 652027 | 871369 | 227209 | 4184.87 | 4968.24 | 7121.13 | 7724.88 | 14130.41 | 5171.08 | 7157.51 | 1896.72 |
| 35 | she | p | 3188078 | 3210.48 | 206627 | 0.93 | 181410 | 217759 | 483074 | 354703 | 1283180 | 285458 | 295580 | 87513 | 1460.00 | 1693.13 | 3771.82 | 2812.08 | 10844.81 | 2263.90 | 2427.92 | 730.55 |

Comment: From the [Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/he) under  **Definition of *he* (Entry 1 of 5):** 2 — *used in a generic sense or when the gender of the person is unspecified.*

Comment: Make sure not to count *He* - Helium, *HE* - hight explosive, His Excellency, Her Excellency

Comment: The general use of 'he' has seen recent change to using 'they' as an unspecified singular pronoun.

Comment: And to confuse things even more, ‘she’ can be used for ships and airplanes, and other vehicles and machinery as well.

Comment: Yes, there is “deeply rooted sexism and gender imbalance.” 

Paraphrasing Karl Marx, “So far, scholars have merely interpreted the dictionary. The point, however, is to change it.” —(pronouns: he, him, his)

Comment: I see, I didn't realize singular they is so recent, that even in the web corpus, it wouldn't make a dent.

Comment: Well and that leads to the more complicated question, how many of the extra 100% are the neutral context he?

Comment: @PetrDoležal Singular they is actually pretty old, but its use has increased in recent years due to more sensitivity about sexism in language.

Comment: BTW, you can't use _than_ with _as...as_ equatives, even ones like _twice as common as_. _Than_ can occur **only** with the comparative (_more/less/-er_) construction.

Comment: I'd guess much is due to biases in the source texts for the corpora, but don't want to give an answer without hard evidence/figures. Look at what they come from. Most journalism is still about men, who still hold the majority of newsworthy positions (politician, military leader, business leader, sports people, criminal). Even scientific papers in fields such as medicine [overwhelmingly focus on men](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8812498/).

Comment: @Barmar You are right that singular *they* is actually quite old—I believe it appears a few times in Shakespeare. However, for much of the 20th century, there was a campaign by schoolteachers and copyeditors to eradicate it from the English language.

Comment: @PeterShor Like the schoolteachers who tried to put a stop to splitting infinitives and ending a sentence with a preposition? Or shamed students who asked "Can I go to the bathroom?" by answering, "I don't know, can you?"

Answer (score 4):

Per [Ngram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+%2F+she&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) "he" was between 4 and 8 times as common as "she" up until 1970, after which this ratio rapidly declined, with the ratio now standing at roughly 1.4:1. Presumably this has something to do with the rise of second-wave feminism (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-wave_feminism)) and a reduction in sexism, but I don't think it's possible to *prove* this; I suspect that the increased entry of women into the workforce was the largest factor.

It used to be that "he" was sometimes used as a gender-neutral pronoun to refer to someone of unknown or unspecified gender, but the decline in that usage of "he" was *itself* due to its being perceived as sexist, so the ultimate cause would be the same.

Comment: It used to be that "he" was the ***only*** gender-neutral pronoun acceptable to teachers and many grammarians (even though *they* was not uncommonly used by us unrefined speakers). I believe I remember being corrected on this usage in my school years (so probably in the late 60s or early 70s). Thus, "he" would clearly have been predominant in print.

Comment: There was a fad for "she" as a gender-neutral pronoun, particularly in academic use, maybe in the 1980s or 90s. But I doubt this has made much difference.